# MS Access: How can I count duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table looks like this...

```
PersonID    Data1    Data2
1           XXXX     YYYY
1           BBBB     YYYY
2           BBBB     YYYY
3           XXXX     YYYY
```

I'd like it to look like this...

```
PersonID    SubRank    Data1    Data2
1           1          XXXX     YYYY
1           2          BBBB     YYYY
2           1          BBBB     YYYY
3           1          XXXX     YYYY
```

The closest solution I've come up with looks like this... (ID is the database access unique ID)

```
SELECT TABLE.PersonID, DCount("ID","Table","(PersonID='"&[PersonID]&"')",) AS SubRank, Table.Data1, Table.Data2
FROM Table
ORDER BY Table.PersonID;
```

But that only returns the total value for the the unique rows (i.e. Subrank is "2" both times for PersonID #1).  Eventually this query will feed a crosstab query to get all the data for a single personID onto one row.

I grabbed the solution above from here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39231&page=1

I'd like to accomplish the same goal, however, their code just isn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to narrow the domain.  You can see in the solution that he has

```
and 
(Date <= #" & [Date] & "#)")
```

inside of the dcount function.  So you need to do something like that as well -- though I'd imagine you're going to use ID instead of date.  Maybe something like this:

```
DCount("ID","Table","(PersonID='"&[PersonID]&"') and (PersonID <= " & [PersonID] & ")" )
```

Comment: OK, I tried that and I'm still getting the same answer.  I checked the original solution and I think they were trying to limit the results to those only before a certain date...  Hence the "<=Date" logic.  Maybe there was a change in how DCount is implemented, I'm running MS Access 2007 and their solution appears to be from the 2005 era.

Comment: Seems like it should have worked -- oh well.  I think Access will let you do inline subqueries...not sure.  Check this out -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa217680%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Access does allow subqueries and I was able to implement something similar to the example, however, I'm running into the same problem. Their subquery example solves ties by awarding the same rank twice... I need to figure out a way to have it increment the rank no matter what...

Comment: Kuru was right after all!! I needed to reference the unique ID rather than the PersonID which would've always been a duplicate. 'DCount("ID","Table","(PersonID='"&[PersonID]&"') and (uniqueID <= " & [uniqueID] & ")" )' where uniqueID is the database unique ID

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is a little vague here. Do you want to find the count of duplicates? Do you want to un-duplicate?  Why not do this:

> SELECT count(*), Data1, Data2 FROM Table GROUP BY Data1, Data2